# SerialPort object throws DataReceived event when data was received before opening the port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have this code to open a serial port:

```
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort(portName);
            port.BaudRate = 9600;
            port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            _serialPorts.Add(name, port);
            port.Open();
            port.DiscardInBuffer();
            port.DataReceived += port_DataReceived;
```

The problem is that if a data is received before the call to Open, port_DataReceived is called with the pending data.

I have addded port.DiscardBuffer call just in case, but this does not work either.

Any help?

Comment: Do you open the port and close it multiple times in your application or just once ? and if yes: when are you facing the issue; after the first open call in your application or the next ones ?

Comment: @AbdullahDibas yes... I open the port once... received some data... then close. When it is closed, I send some more data to COM port.... then I open the port again, and after doing so, DataReceived event is called, reading the data sent when port was closed.

Comment: @AbdullahDibas by the way, SerialPort.Open method is called using different instances of the class.

Comment: I am not sure about the issue , but I am assuming that it's possible that the data received event was already scheduled in the threads pool before the previous close call.

Comment: Also I think you can make an ugly workaround by not handling the first event received within like 1 second after opening the port, if you can ensure that no data is transmitted to this port within this short interval.

Comment: @AbdullahDibas I am sure the port is closed before other data was sent to it... and I am even calling Dispose on the SerialPort object after closing it.

Comment: Did you try to call ReadExisting instead of DiscardInBuffer ?

Comment: Finally I kept the COM port opened all the time, until the application closes. I subscribed to the DataReceived event before actually using the connection and unsuscribed to it when connection it is not more needed while application is running. However, I do still need to call DiscardInBuffer if some data was received by the port before event was subscribed.

Comment: @AbdullahDibas Yes... I tried that after opening the port and before event subscription. ReadExisting returned empty string, however, after event subscription, event method is called anyway. Strange.

Comment: Please clarify your question, it's not clear what you are trying to do.  Saying data recieved before opening doesn't tell us anything.  Also, you should finish initializing your SerialPort object before opening it. Try adding the event before you open the port.